# How To reset appropriate parameters for the modification of existing values in java

Tags: java, parameters

I want to change these details of Benze car from user input values.
User will be able to change existing details from user input (ex: Name, Brand..).
How to reset the appropriate parameters to change the existing values?

```java
Automobile Benze[] = new Automobile [5];
Benze[i]=new Automobile();  //Automobile is my class name 
  
do { 
                     
    System.out.println("01<Mercedize Benze");
                    
    String C = T.readLine();
    int ch = Integer.valueOf(C).intValue(); 
                     
    switch(ch) {

    case 01:
        //Details of Benze car
        Name = "Benze Class C";
        Brand = "Benz";
        Start = "On ";
        Colour= "Grey";
        Fuel = 3.5;
        Km = 9;
        Oil = 1.2;
        water = 2;
                          
        for( i=0; i < 1; i++) {
            Benze [i] = new Automobile(Name, Brand, Start, Colour, Fuel, Km, Oil, water);
                            
            Benze[i].show();
        }


} while(exit == true);
```

Comment: Java naming conventions have variables and methods starting with a lower case letter; classes start with an upper case letter. This makes a program easier to read and debug.

Comment: This code snippet does not seem to compile because `i` and other variables are not defined, `do-while` loop is not closed, `switch` statement is not closed.  Please try to provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `mutate` ➡️ use `setters`:

```
class Automobile {
    private String name;
    ...
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    ...
}
```

```
var auto = Benze[i];
auto.setName("new name");
```

, but better approach is creation `new` one

```
var old = Benze[i];
Benze[i] = new Automobile("new name", old.getBrand, ...);
```

Comment: I did like this but it doesn't gives other current values from "get" method                  //changing 
       case 01:
         System.out.println("give a new name ");
        Name= T.readLine();
        var old1 = Benze[i]; 
         
        old1.setName(Name);
        Benze[i] = new Automobile(Name, old1.getBrand ( ),old1.getStart (),
        old1.getColour( ),old1.getFuel(),old1.getKm(),old1.getWater(),old1.getOil());
        
        old1.show();

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be incomplete. Please show us the whole thing, including your automobile class.
Also, please always use meaningful variable names. We can never tell what something like C Is supposed to do.

As for your questions, if I understand correctly, you need to create setters for your properties, and then invoke them.

For example, a setter for a name would be
In the automobile class

`public void setName(String newName){ this.name = newName; }`

And that's it, you just invoke the method from elsewhere and pass it a name parameter. Do this for each property you want to modify, or create a method that changes all of them. The important part is understanding that you can change the properties by just using this.whatever = something